# Eureka to Consul issue for spring cloud

Tags: spring-cloud

We are moving our large set of eureka based microservices to consul based discovery.

There was one feature of the eureka version of spring cloud that we were used.  You could register a specific hostname such as "hostname: blah".

Is a capability like that present in the spring cloud consul version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.hostname`. It's not documented, but it should show in IDE auto-complete with the note on what it is for.

See [ConsulDiscoveryProperties](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/spring-cloud-consul-discovery/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/consul/discovery/ConsulDiscoveryProperties.java).